# How to disable mouse activity when the value in a table is not in proper format?

Tags: java, jtable, mouse

I have a `JTable` with several columns. I override the `getColumnClass` method of the table model in order to specify which columns hold `Integer` values. So basically when a user tries to enter a `String` into an `Integer` column, he/she is not allowed to do so. The problem is that the user can still click on a button on my form which then uses the improper value in that cell.

How can I not allow the user to click on any buttons as long as one of the cells in the table is still being edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a PropertyChangeListener to the JTable:

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
{
    //  A cell has started/stopped editing

    if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
    {
        if (table.isEditing())
            // disable buttons;
        else
            // enable buttons;
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to disable the buttons, you can just add code to the ActionListener to check if the table.isEditing() and if so then just return.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up adding code to the ActionListener and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the 3 methods returning information on the editing process to enable your button.

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.getEditingColumn();
table.getEditingRow();
table.getEditorComponent();
```

Check [JTable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getEditingColumn%28%29) to see which could be best used for your case. You could make your button enabled only if

```
table.getEditorComponent();
```

returns `null` for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a TableModelListener to your JTable
2. you should override its tableChanged method somewhat like this :

   ```
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
   int row = e.getFirstRow();
   int column = e.getColumn();
   TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
   String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
   Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
   //Check the data!!!
   //Check the data!!!
   //Check the data!!!
   //disable the button if needed right here
   }
   ```

ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange